# Python EOF for multi byte requests of file.read()

Tags: python, eof

The Python docs on [file.read()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) state that `An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately.` The documentation further states:

> Note that this method may call the
>   underlying C function fread() more
>   than once in an effort to acquire as
>   close to size bytes as possible. Also
>   note that when in non-blocking mode,
>   less data than was requested may be
>   returned, even if no size parameter
>   was given.

I believe Guido has made his view on not adding f.eof() [PERFECTLY CLEAR](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-January/011445.html) so need to use the Python way!

What is not clear to ME, however, is if it is a definitive test that you have reached EOF if you receive less than the requested bytes from a read, but you did receive some.

ie:

```
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    while True:
        s=f.read(size)
        l=len(s) 
        if l==0: 
            break     # it is clear that this is EOF...
        if l<size:
            break      # ? Is receiving less than the request EOF???
```

Is it a potential error to `break` if you have received less than the bytes requested in a call to `file.read(size)`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are not thinking with your snake skin on... Python is not C.

First, a review:

- st=f.read() reads to EOF, or if opened as a binary, to the last byte;
- st=f.read(n) *attempts* to reads `n` bytes and in no case more than `n` bytes;
- st=f.readline() reads a line at a time, the line ends with '\n' or EOF;
- st=f.readlines() uses readline() to read all the lines in a file and returns a list of the lines.

If a file read method is at EOF, it returns `''`. The same type of EOF test is used in the other 'file like" methods like StringIO, socket.makefile, etc. A return of less than `n` bytes from `f.read(n)` is most assuredly NOT a dispositive test for EOF! While that code may work 99.99% of the time, it is the times it does not work that would be very frustrating to find. Plus, it is bad Python form. The only use for `n` in this case is to put an upper limit on the size of the return.

What are some of the reasons the Python file-like methods returns *less* than `n` bytes?

1. EOF is certainly a common reason;
2. A network socket may timeout on read yet remain open;
3. Exactly `n` bytes may cause a break between logical multi-byte characters (such as `\r\n` in text mode and, I think, a multi-byte character in Unicode) or some underlying data structure not known to you;
4. The file is in non-blocking mode and another process begins to access the file;
5. Temporary non-access to the file;
6. An underlying error condition, potentially temporary, on the file, disc, network, etc.
7. The program received a signal, but the signal handler ignored it.

I would rewrite your code in this manner:

```
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    while True:
        s=f.read(max_size)
        if not s: break

        # process the data in s...
```

Or, write a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855):

```
def blocks(infile, bufsize=1024):
    while True:
        try:
            data=infile.read(bufsize)
            if data:
                yield data
            else:
                break
        except IOError as (errno, strerror):
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
            break

f=open('somefile','rb')

for block in blocks(f,2**16):
    # process a block that COULD be up to 65,536 bytes long
```

Comment: "such as \r\n in binary mode" <- should this have said "text mode" rather than "binary mode"?  In binary mode, it would just be a pair of bytes like any other, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my C compiler's documentation says for the `fread()` function:

```
size_t fread( 
   void *buffer,
   size_t size,
   size_t count,
   FILE *stream 
);
```

> **fread** returns the number of full items
>   actually read, which may be less than
>   count if an error occurs or if the end
>   of the file is encountered before
>   reaching count.

So it looks like getting less than `size` means either an error has occurred or EOF has been reached -- so `break`ing out of the loop would be the correct thing to do.

Comment: This is not correct, a signal may cause a short read that causes less bytes to be returned... which is not exactly the an EOF.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I would argue that if a short read occurs because the program received a signal, but the signal handler ignored it, the loop still ought to be terminated since signals generally indicate fatal errors or that the users wants to interrupt the process -- so regardless of whether it's exactly an EOF or not, breaking out out of the loop is most likely the correct thing to do.

Comment: I agree that is it sane for a signal handler to cause a short read, but I disagree that it is an error condition. One of my scripts keeps processing data from stdin until EOF. `SIGUSR1` is configured to flush data immediately, this causes a short read which is expected and *not* an error.