# Python f.read not reading the correct number of bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code that is supposed to read 4 bytes but it is only reading 3 sometimes:

```
f = open('test.sgy', 'r+')
f.seek(99716)
AAA = f.read(4)
BBB = f.read(4)
CCC = f.read(4)
print len(AAA)
print len(BBB)
print len(CCC)

exit()
```

And this program returns:
4
3
4

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What does `print repr(BBB)` show?  I'm going to hazard a guess that you'll see a newline character (`\n`) in the output.  If so, the solution is probably to open your file in binary mode: `f = open('test.sgy', 'rb+')`.

Comment: Some possible causes are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4433813/270986.  Opening in binary mode would be the first thing to try, though.

Answer (score 7):

You're assuming `read` does something it does not. As its documentation tells you:

```
read(...)
    read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.
```

it reads **at most** `size` bytes

If you need *exactly* `size` bytes, you'll have to create a wrapper function.

---

Here's a (not thoroughly tested) example that you can adapt:

```
def read_exactly( fd, size ):
    data=""
    remaining= size
    while remaining>0:      #or simply "while remaining", if you'd like
        newdata= fd.read(remaining)
        if len(newdata)==0: #problem
            raise IOError("Failed to read enough data")
        data+=newdata
        remaining-= len(newdata)
    return data
```

---

As Mark Dickinson mentioned in the comments, if you're on Windows, make sure you're [reading in binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) - otherwise you risk `read`ing your (binary) data wrong.

Comment: I suspect this is going to give bad results: if the reason for the missing byte is that a `\r\n` got translated into a `\n` by Python's text-mode file-reading machinery, then reading another byte on top of that isn't going to fix the corruption that's already crept in.  Opening in binary mode is critical here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I wasn't aware that situation could cause a short read - note the answer you linked to mentions `\r\n`causing a short read *on binary mode*. The [type of file the OP is reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEG_Y) may have textual records, but I thought it unlikely that OP would be grabbing 3 byte chunks of those. Notwithstanding, reading in binary mode is still a good idea, and I'll add it to my answer, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Looking at the OP's other recent question, it looks as though it was a Ctrl-Z that was the problem, not a `\r\n`.  I think that the short read in *binary mode* for `\r\n` in that other question must have been a typo; it doesn't make any sense to me.  And yes, SEG-Y is in some sense a mixed binary and text format.  (I've lost *way* too many hours of my life looking at SEG-Y files. ;-).

Comment: @goncalopp: And you're absolutely right: an `\r\n` can't cause a short read (I've just managed to find a Windows machine to test on).  It turns out that the `n` given refers to the number of *output* characters, so it would cause `f.read(4)` to still return 4 bytes, but to advance 5 bytes in the underlying file.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The way I interpreted the answer you linked to was that `read` would refuse to return (binary) data if it would cut `\r\n` in half - though I tried it here and it cut it happily. But we're probably digging too much into implementation details, and behavior could differ across versions and platforms