# how to transform bytes to float with python?

Tags: python

I got a binary file written in java.I want to read the file with python,and convert every 4 bytes to a float.

the first 4 bytes is `bce9 1165`,but I read it is `b'\xbc\xe9\x11e'` by the code

```
with open(filename, "rb+") as f:
    f.read(4)
```

it's different！

Then I convert it by `struct.unpack('f',data1)`.but I got the wrong float.
the wrong float is `4.30659236383095e+22`. but it's truly `-0.028450677`
so how to decode it？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your float is encoded in big-endian format. To decode it, give `struct.unpack` the `'>f'` format string (the `>` explicitly tells it to use big-endian format, rather than your system's native byte order):

```
>>> struct.unpack('>f', b'\xbc\xe9\x11e')
(-0.028450677171349525,)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f.read(4) is your issue here
```

file.read reads at most size bytes and returns.[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

You'll have to create a wrapper function to read exact bytes.

You can get inspiration from here :[Check link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393785/python-f-read-not-reading-the-correct-number-of-bytes)